# doctrine 2 findAll() out of memory error

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Out of memory error is coming in doctrine 2. When I try to fetch all data from one table. My database is little bigger but table data is not too much...

```
 //fetching data from table by another way
            $data = $em->getRepository('User');
            $datax = $data->findAll();

            foreach($datax as $d) {
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($d); echo '</pre>';
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dump()` method from doctrine's `Debug` class, don't use print_r() on doctrine objects this is what which will be causing out of memory error

```
\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($d);
```

Or use [LadybugBundle](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle) to dump objects